# html: how to make all the DIVs in the center of the page?

Tags: html

like:

```
<body>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</body>
```

How can I make all the DIVs at the center of the webpage?

I mean in the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div class="center"></div>
```

CSS:

```
div.center { margin: 0 auto; }
```

Of course, if you have other things outside of those divs, they might interfere.

Comment: the divs need to have a specific width set for this to work, e.g. `div.center { margin: 0 auto; width: 800px }`

Comment: I conditionally accepts this answer, the Graham Clark has a more accurate complement comment.

Answer (score 1):

Either create a CSS class or put a style in your `DIV` element:

```
margin:0px auto;
```

Comment: `px` is redundant, because any unit multiplied by zero is zero anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the exact page, but either `text-align: center` or `margin: 0 auto` will probably be what you need. See [CSS Centering](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/center/) for general information about centering and [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) so you know how to target the proper elements.

Comment: If you use text-align: center; ensure you then use text-align: left; on the content within the divs, otherwise everything will be centred.

Comment: Yup, it says exactly that in the CSS Centering link I posted.